# How to move node_modules folder to common location to access in all Angular2 apps

Tags: angularjs, angular

Is there a way to move **node_modules** folder to common location ex: **C:\angular2** and access in different apps ex: **C:\angular2\angular2-quickstart**, **C:\angular2\angular2-tour-of-heroes** etc..

Only for learning angular2, I am creating applications. node_module folder is about 80mb. So instead of every time copy and pasting is there a way to place it in common location.

Comment: i think yes you can...move node_modules into some common folder and then from that folder create you project folders. by this way you have to bootstrap no of file as per one project one bootstrap file

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you can do.

I have node_modules directory stored in C:\common folder

```
On windows:

Go to your project folder

    mklink /j node_modules C:\common\node_modules

    ng serve --preserve-symlinks

On Linux:

ln -s ~/common/node_modules node_modules
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to go to the common module **C:\angular2|common** (the directory where the package.json is), and then do:

```
npm link
```

And then from the directory where you want to consume the module (for example **C:\angular2\angular2-tour-of-heroes**) do:

```
npm link your-common-module-package-name
```

This effective creates a file system link between the module using the the common module, and the common module. Have a look here for [some documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) about the npm link feature.

Another possibility besides `npm link` is to add the common folder to the `NODE_PATH` environment variable (check [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) some docs).

Comment: jhadesdev.. you meant here npm link ..\common ?

Comment: edited adding another possibility besides npm link, using the NODE_PATH environment variable