# How to set node_module/... lib path in angular js

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have to try See in the image it is working fine.

How can we use global lib for node_module

it is install properly in 
place -

> **c:\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules**

but i am not able to use in my angular2 js project.

Please let me know how can be use **c:\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules**

dir[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prYBA.png)

Image

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183252/how-to-move-node-modules-folder-to-common-location-to-access-in-all-angular2-app

Answer (score 2):

In App.js (of Node) Add the following line :

```
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(<path-of-your-dir>));
```

So, you can use it like the following :

```
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
```

I think this will helps :)

Comment: Can you please suggest me for angular2.0

Comment: If yes then please try to do above settings. Might it helps to solve your problem